# Callback for when JS SDK is initialized AND ready for making API calls

Tags: javascript, sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm loading the JS SDK async and running FB.init inside the fbAsyncInit callback. After FB.init is run I want to do a API call as soon as possible, but when doing the API call just after FB.init I get the following OAuthException

> Object { type="OAuthException", message="An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}

If I delay the API call with X seconds it works. So, how do I get a callback when the SDK is ready for API calls?

See code example below. The argument "authResponse" to FB.init is generated by the PHP SDK (getSignedRequest()).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<button onclick="getMe();">Get me</button>

<script>
    function getMe() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
</script>

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script style="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        console.log("fbAsyncInit called");
        FB.init({appId: "XXX", status: true, cookie: false, authResponse: {"algorithm":"HMAC-SHA256","expires":1314802800,"issued_at":1314798072,"oauth_token":"XXX","user":{"country":"se","locale":"en_US","age":{"min":21}},"user_id":"XXX"}, oauth: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.api("/me", function(response) {console.log(response);});
    };
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement("script"); e.async = true;
        e.src = document.location.protocol + "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js";
        document.getElementById("fb-root").appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you subscribe to the `auth.statusChange` event immediately after `FB.init` is called I believe it gets called when you get a session, and it is then safe to use `FB.api`. [See the docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) on `FB.Event.subscribe` for more detail.

Comment: Didn't work. The event occurs and the response object passed to the callback function looks valid and has a working oauth_token.

Comment: If your solution doesn't work next time I try then I'm gonna report it as a bug.